# Java Makefile always rebuilds, even when no changes were made

Tags: java, makefile

My makefile always rebuilds the project, even if no changes were made.

How can I fix it?

My project structure follows the usual bin/, src/, Makefile pattern.

Makefile:

```
# output directory
BIN = bin/

# input directory
SRC = src/

# java compiler
JC = javac

# compile flags
JFLAGS = -d $(BIN) -cp $(SRC)

sourcefiles = $(addprefix $(SRC), \
  A.java \
  B.java \
  C.java)

classfiles = $(sourcefiles:.java=.class)

all: $(classfiles)

%.class: %.java
  $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<

clean:
  $(RM)  $(BIN)*.class
```

I made this makefile from examples I found online, but I'm not sure I understand everything being done, so if I could also get an explanation, that would be great :3

Comment: Why are you using make for Java? There are Java build tools (Maven and Gradle) that are both easier and more reliable.

Comment: How are you invoking `make`? If your invocation triggers the `clean` target that could explain what you observe. Also, `$(SRC)` is not the classpath, it's the sourcepath. You have `classfiles` defined by substituting just the suffixes of the files, but they also should be in a different directory, yes? So that could explain what you observe, since `$(classfiles)` will always be empty. And as @chrylis let you know, `make` is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `make` is not a good fit for Java.  Make works best with tools that behave similarly to traditional compilers: they take an input file `foo.X` (and maybe some other input files as well) and they generate a single output file `foo.Y`.  For a C compiler for example `X` is `c` and `Y` is `o` (`foo.c` compiles to `foo.o`).

Make is hard to use in situations where a single invocation of the compiler generates more than one output file, and it's not simple to use when the name of the output file doesn't relate directly to the name of the input file (in this case you have to write all explicit rules, not pattern rules).

For Java compilers a single `.java` input file can generate multiple different `.class` files, and the names of the `.class` files are not necessarily related to the name of the `.java` file.

In your situation, I'll bet if you look at the output files that `javac` is generating for your `A.java` file you'll see it's not generating `A.class`.  Because `A.class` doesn't exist, make will always try to rebuild it.

Oh.  Also.  You're putting files in different directories.  So even if you DO restrict yourself to situations where the names are identical, you have to write your pattern like this:

```
# ... Keep the first part as in your example

classfiles = $(patsubst $(SRC)%.java,$(BIN)%.class,$(sourcefiles))

all: $(classfiles)

$(BIN)%.class : $(SRC)%.java
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<

# ... Keep the clean rule as in your example
```

The patterns `%` must be identical; if you put things in different directories they're not identical.

Comment: Yes, I am restricting myself to cases where the ``.java`` and ``.class`` have the same name. I do understand what you mean though, so maybe I'll look into other ways to build the projects besides Makefile. However, your solution didn't work, now ``make`` always states there's nothing to be built.

Comment: You did keep the `all` target, right?  I didn't mean for you to take it out, I was just including the lines that needed to be changed and not the lines that didn't need to be changed.  I'll update.

Comment: Oh.  You put the backslash in the variable SRC / BIN.  I never do that and I forget that sometimes people do.  You need a slightly different patsubst.  I'll fix.

Comment: Thank you, it works now :) I've marked it as the accepted answer. One question though: I'm trying to compile 5 ``.java`` files. And while they do all get compiled into the respective 5 ``.class`` files, the terminal only shows the instructions ``javac -d bin -cp src/ src/X.java`` for 4 of them when I run ``make``. Is this normal? o.O

Comment: No, I can't explain that.  Make always prints every rule it runs (assuming you don't prefix the recipe with `@` to silence it).  If it doesn't print a javac command for a particular file then it didn't rebuild that file.  Maybe the `.class` file for that `.java` file already existed and was up to date, so make didn't need to recreate it.

Comment: That wasn't the case though. It's also a mystery to me. Even if there are no ``.class`` files, only 4 of the 5 ``javac`` commands are printed to the terminal.

Comment: You can try running `make -d` and see what make says about that other `.java` file.  Note output is voluminous so redirect to a file.

Comment: Interesting... ``make`` states ``No need to remake target 'bin/X.class'.`` because ``X.java`` is older than ``X.class``. This is really weird though, since I removed all ``.class`` files before running ``make``. Is it possible that one of the other ``.java`` files is forcing the compilation of ``X.java`` before ``make`` looks at its target?

Comment: It would have to be javac doing this.  If make did it, then you'd see the output.  What you can try is running `make bin/foo.class` one at a time for each `.java` file and figure out which one is causing `bin/X.class` to be created as a side-effect, if you want to know.  Maybe it doesn't really matter though.  I'm not a Java expert so I don't know.